# How to compare two results files in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

As per requirement I need to compare two jmeter results files of different environments. as I'm new in Jmeter can someone let me know how it can be possible

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the plugin [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/)? With this JMeter plugin can merge result files and compare it.

Comment: It is merging the csv files.  But I dont see it comparing. It is just listing the results one below the other for me

Comment: There is an article here that describes step-by-step how to use the Merge Results plugin and generate a new JMeter Dashboard Report comparing the results from two or more tests: https://www.redline13.com/blog/2023/08/compare-jmeter-test-results/

Answer (score 0):

For all the analysis and reporting that is available for each test run using JMeter (using the [JMeter Dashboard Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)), comparing the results of two different test runs is not something that is as robustly supported.  There are several approaches which can be briefly summarized as follows:

- **CSV data comparison**: All of the results of a JMeter test run are saved to a `JTL` file, which is essentially a CSV file with a different file extension.  One of the simplest ways to compare two or more tests (as [described here](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2022/03/compare-load-tests-results-using-csv-data/)) is to load multiple CSV files into your favorite spreadsheet software (*e.g.*, Excel) and perform formulary analysis, generate graphs, *etc*.
- **Timeseries database tools**: There are a number of timeseries database tools that integrate well with JMeter.  [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/products/influxdb/) and [Dynatrace](https://www.dynatrace.com/) are two notable examples.  While these require modification to your test and setup prior to test runs, they can capture very granular and detailed metrics that can directly be used to compare results between separate JMeter test runs.
- **JMeter *[Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/)* plugin**: This is a plugin for JMeter that confers built-in functionality to compare the results of two (or more) JMeter test runs.  It works via the JMeter GUI on `JTL` files after-the-fact, and generates a new merged `JTL` file that can be then used to generate a JMeter Dashboard report or other similar analysis.  There are provisions in this tool to supply a time offset to make test runs coincide for side-by-side analysis.
- **AI assistants (such as [ChatGPT](https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt/))**: One thing that ChatGPT and related AI assistant products are surprisingly good at is writing short scripts (*e.g.*, Python) to perform simple tasks.  ChatGPT has understanding of how JMeter `JTL` files are structured, and one may ask the assistant directly to create code which analyzes or graphs results in a number of ways, as described in [this article](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2023/09/chatgpt-to-analyze-jmeter-results/).